# What's wrong in this code for firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to be able to copy the uid(underlined in blue in the picture) and compare it with the current user's uid. And, alow writing to the database only if there isn't data under the same uid. This is to allow each user upload data only once.

[Link to the database screenshot](https://ibb.co/iZXY9k)

```
buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mDatabaseReference.child("drivers").child(userid).toString() != userid || mDatabaseReference.child("parents").child(userid).toString() != useremail) {
            if (!radiobutton1.isChecked() && !radiobutton2.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(LoggedinActivity.this, "Please select either Driver or Parent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == radiobutton1.getId()) {
                typestring = "driver";
                Users users = new Users(useremail, editText.getText().toString(), typestring);
                mDatabaseReference.child("drivers").child(userid).setValue(users);
            } else if (radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == radiobutton2.getId()) {
                typestring = "parent";
                Users users = new Users(useremail, editText.getText().toString(), typestring);
                mDatabaseReference.child("parents").child(userid).setValue(users);
            }
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(LoggedinActivity.this, "Information already submitted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }     
    }
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You didn't tell us what your problem is - this means we can't help you.

Comment: It's not supposed to add data if there's already data under the current user's uid. But, it replaces the data if there's already one under the current user's uid. Which it isn't supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
mDatabaseReference.child("drivers").child(userid).toString() != userid || mDatabaseReference.child("parents").child(userid).toString() != useremail) {
```

with

```
mDatabaseReference.child("drivers").child(userid).getRef().toString() != userid || mDatabaseReference.child("parents").getRef().child(userid).toString() != useremail) {
```

As you probably see, i have added the `getRef()` method to actually get the reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Let me try this code.

Comment: I'm sorry but that code doesn't work. What it's doing now is that it's uploads data if I change the name in the edittext. And, it is able to upload data to both driver section and parent section . I want it to be able to upload just once to either drivers or parents

Comment: Then change the logic accordingly. Remeber, `getRef()` method is mandatory.

Comment: What does getRef() do? I'm sorry for asking silly questions because this is just my second app and i don't know a lot.

Comment: getRef() is actually gettting the reference of the record you want to compare.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. If you think that my answer helped you in any way, please consider accepting it. Thanks!